# Visual Format Language Multiple Predicates

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout, visual-format-language

I am working with Visual Format Language and I run in to an issue.

Take for example the Multiple Predicates example of Apple:

[Apple Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH27-SW1)

Multiple Predicates

> [flexibleButton(>=70,<=100)]

If I want the size of the button at its normal state to be 100 and if that does not work the button can decrease till 70. How can I achieve this?

My example looks like this:

> "H:|-(>=10)-[Textfield]-(>=5,<=50)-[firstButton]-(<=50)-[secondButton]-(>=10)-|"

So I want to have a standard margin of 50 but if that does not work the Textfield is allowed to expand till 5 but not any further. What is the usual way to make that happen? Because right now it just chooses the "5"-Constraint and stays there.

Comment: You need priorities for that and that means not using visual language. Its much easier in interface builder anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually your answer helped me but you are wrong. That is my solution: "H:|-(>=10)-[Textfield]-(50@800,>=5@790)-[firstButton]-(<=50)-[secondButton]-(>=10)-|" and: 
Textfield.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750), for: .horizontal)

Comment: I tend to use interface builder and I forgot you can write priorities that way using visual language :) Your constraints are still ambigious though. If you have `>=10` twice, it means you never know which one of them gets increased.

Comment: I center the base view horizontally in an other constraint, but yes thanks you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used priorities, now it does work.
This is my solution:

Visual language:

> "H:|-(>=10)-[Textfield]-(50@800,>=5@790)-[firstButton]-(<=50)-[secondButton]-(>=10)-|"

On top of that I had to set the priority of the compression resistance.

```
Textfield.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750), for: .horizontal)
```